# How to automate object adding in the django model?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the model for a team object. I want to add objects in this models by parsing. So, I have parsing code in the views.py. How can I do adding of that data in the model in the views.py. Should I use queryset or something like that?

As I know there is approach to add objects using Django shell. But is it possible to add objects automatically? While the project is deployed on a hosting it is not possible to use Django shell. I tried to use manual adding using lists and dictionaries as the variable during template rendering.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen


def homePage(request):
    tn = []
    ti = []
    for team in teamList:
        tn.append({'name': team})

    for img in imgList:
        tn.append({'img': img})

    teamDict = {
        'team': tn,
        'matchLink': linkSrc,
        'img': tn,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', teamDict)


# Parser
try:
    html = urlopen("//some url//")
except:
    print("Connection problems")


teamList = []
imgList = []
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
futMatches = bsObj.find("div", {"class": "esport-match-future-list"})
for link in futMatches.find_all("div", {"class": "esport-match-single"}):
    linkTag = link.find("a", {"class": "team-vs-team"})
    if "tbd" not in linkTag.attrs["href"]:
        teamDiv = linkTag.find_all("div", {"class": "team"})
        for item in teamDiv:
            name = item.find("span", {"class": "name"}).text
            photo1 = item.find_all("img")
            for img in photo1:
                imgSrc = "https://dota2.ru" + img.attrs["src"]
                imgList.append({"img": imgSrc})
            teamList.append({"name": name})
        linkSrc = "https://dota2.ru" + linkTag.attrs["href"]  # Match link



# End of parser
```

```
from django.db import models

class Match(models.Model):
    team1 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Team 1')
    team2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Team 2')
    #matchTime = models.DateTimeField()
    tour = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Tournament')

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Team')
    urlslug = models.SlugField(max_length=5)

    #Player 1 info
    player1Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Player')
    player1Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='')
    player1Nation = models.ImageField(upload_to='')

    #Player 2 info
    player2Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Player')
    player2Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='')
    player2Nation = models.ImageField(upload_to='')

    #Player 3 info
    player3Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Player')
    player3Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='')
    player3Nation = models.ImageField(upload_to='')

    #Player 4 info
    player4Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Player')
    player4Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='')
    player4Nation = models.ImageField(upload_to='')

    #Player 5 info
    player5Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Player')
    player5Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='')
    player5Nation = models.ImageField(upload_to='')

    #Standin 1 info
    standin1Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Standin', null=True)
    standin1Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True)
    standin1ation = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True)

    #Standin 2 info
    standin2Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Standin', null=True)
    standin2Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True)
    standin2Nation = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True)
```

I want that after the parsing, the data was added to model as new object and finally use the model during the rendering of the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add players and teams automatically from a third-party api, you'll need to call the api, parse the results and then **update the model**. For example, here's a pseudo-code example:

```
def update_team_name(team):

  ...your parsing code here...     

  Team.objects.filter(pk=team.pk).update(name=team.name)
  team.save()
  return True
```

BTW, I would consider restructuring your model: add a Player model. Enhance the team so it includes players and a stand-in indicator.